# upload files to to the same folder

Tags: php

I created function that uploads files. the problem is that I'm calling it from different file and different folders, which means that my path to the image folder's is changing.

how can I set the folder to be absolute?

BTW - I need it to work on my local computer (using WAMP) and from my linux server (where my website located)

```
$usersFiles = './images/usersFiles/';  

if (move_uploaded_file($files['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $usersFiles.$files['file']['name'][$i]))
```

Comment: Don't make it relative, but determine your project root, store that in a constant and work from there.

Comment: @Jelmer - how do I set the root?

Comment: You can do something like `echo dirname(__FILE__));` then use what you get to set the full path to the `userFiles` folder

Comment: @cmorrissey : __FILE__ is the same as  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to get the path to the root level of your website, e.g.

```
$usersFiles = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images/usersFiles/';  

if (move_uploaded_file($files['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $usersFiles.$files['file']['name'][$i]))
```

Comment: still not working: Warning: move_uploaded_file(http://localhost/dogger/images/usersFiles/13981065060-1.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\dogger\func\func.global.php on line 127

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\tmp\phpB0F3.tmp' to 'http://localhost/dogger/images/usersFiles/13981065060-1.jpg' in C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\dogger\func\func.global.php on line 127

Comment: That's strange... sorry it may be a WAMP issue that I'm not familiar with. I would expect $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to give you an absolute path to the root level of the website, something like "C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\dogger." But from the error output it seems like it's just generating "localhost." Could you repost the error message inside a code block so that the stack overflow formatter doesn't try to turn things into links? Thanks.

Comment: well, it a little bite more complex. can I contact u via email?